# Spring MVC With Junit Test does not work when testing Dao: NULL pointer

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit4

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
<context:property-placeholder location="/config.properties" />
<bean id="myDataSource"
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

And This is my Dao:

```
package com.dao.impl;

import com.dao.UniversityBasicInformationDao;
import com.message.Message;
import com.message.imp.UniversityMessage;
import com.model.UniversityBasicInformation;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class UniversityBasicInformationImp implements 
UniversityBasicInformationDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static Logger logger;

public Message[] getAll() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

    List list = session.createQuery("FROM UniversityBasicInformation ").list();
    session.close();
    Message[] message = new Message[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        UniversityBasicInformation university = (UniversityBasicInformation) list.get(i);
        UniversityMessage universityMessage = new UniversityMessage(university);
        message[i] = universityMessage;
    }
    logger.info(message[0].getJson());
    return message;
}

public Message findByName(String name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    List list = session.createQuery("FROM UniversityBasicInformation " +
    "WHERE universityName = ?").setParameter(0, name).list();
    session.close();

    return new UniversityMessage((UniversityBasicInformation) list.get(0));
}

public Message findByID(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    List list = session.createQuery("FROM UniversityBasicInformation " +
    "WHERE universityId = ?").setParameter(0, id).list();
    session.close();

    return new UniversityMessage((UniversityBasicInformation) list.get(0));
}

public void add(UniversityBasicInformation university) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save(university);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("UniversityBasicInformationDao add Exception: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void remove(UniversityBasicInformation university) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.delete(university);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("UniversityBasicInformationDao delete Exception: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void update(UniversityBasicInformation university) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.update(university);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("UniversityBasicInformationDao delete Exception: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

}

And this is my testDao:

```
package com.dao.impl;


import com.dao.UniversityBasicInformationDao;
import com.message.Message;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
class UniversityBasicInformationImpTest {

@Autowired
private UniversityBasicInformationDao universityBasicInformationDao;

@Test
void getAll() {
    assertFalse(universityBasicInformationDao == null);
    Message[] message = universityBasicInformationDao.getAll();
    assertEquals("{\"university_id\":\"1\"," +
            "\"university_address_line_1\":\"1410 NE Campus Parkway \"," +
            "\"university_address_line_2\":null,\"university_name\":\"University of Washington\"," +
            "\"university_profile_image_id\":\"com.model.ImageObject@2802756f\"}",
            message[0].getJson());

}

}
```

The thing is that it works well when i run tomcat server but when running the test, it throws out a NullPointerException(). I have checked many documentations online, and a lot of other questions in stackoverflow, but it just does not work for me. i was stuck here for nearly whole day, plz save me.